# Define specific category name in PHP

Tags: php, categories

Might be a really simple question... I am trying to pull out a category name in PHP and display it on my page. I have multiple category sections on this page, and each need to pull their respected name as an *h2*. Here is what I am currently doing:

```
<div class="category-section">
    <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
        <?php query_posts('category_name"theCategoryName"');
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            #code...
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I **query_posts** for my `theCategoryName` I get the content needed for that section, however, a couple lines above where I have `the_category()` printing out, this stays the same name for all of my different sections. For example, if the cateogry name was "cats" then for all my sections that have an *h2* show the text "cats".

Lets say this particular section is suppose to be "dogs" instead of "cats", how would I achieve this? Hope this makes sense..

****EDIT****

So here is an updated version of my code, but I am still having issues. `the_category();` for each section still shows up as the same name. AND it seams as though the category name changes if I create a new post with a different category. For example, 
if I create "cars" then both of the below category names change to "cars".

```
<div class="category-1">
    <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
        <?php 
        $q = new WP_Query('category_name="cats"');
        if($q->have_posts()) {
            while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); ?>
                #code...
            <?php 
            endwhile; 
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="category-2">
    <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
        <?php 
        $q = new WP_Query('category_name="dogs"');
        if($q->have_posts()) {
            while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); ?>
                #code...
            <?php 
            endwhile; 
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is my code syntax correct?  or am I just all over the place with this :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise against query_posts for readability purposes as its easier to make mistakes and you can end up muddled when you nest them. ( You also missed out an equals sign in your syntax.

Instead use WP_Query, and check for when no posts are found, e.g. this code:

```
<div class="category-section">
    <h2><?php the_category(); ?></h2>
    <div class="content">
        <?php
        $q = new WP_Query('category_name=theCategoryName');
        if($q->have_posts()){
            while ($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post(); ?>
                #code...
            endwhile;
        } else {
            ?><p>No posts</p><?php
        }
 ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, the root cause of you're problem, you must add a call to this function after you're done with your loop to reset everything back to before the loop.

If you're using `WP_Query` or `get_posts` call `wp_reset_postdata();`

If you're using `query_posts` use `wp_reset_query();`

Remember to reset things after every post loop, always check if there are any posts before starting the loop, and always put the reset after the check, not inside after the loop ( else it won't reset if no posts are found).

Comment: I made some changes as per your suggestions, but continue to have some problems.  Updated code is above. Am I reseting things right?

Comment: Okay your updated code makes your issue clearer. You called the_category and got a result, why do you think calling it again would give you something different? Are you listing all categories? If so you need a loop surrounding everything..

Comment: I'll update my code in the morning after I've slept to demonstrate and explain

Comment: I see what you mean.  Noob mistake, thanks for the clarification.